# Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I click on autocomplete input I am getting;

> Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined

```
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

    $(function () {
        initialize();
    });

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initialize() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
        // to geographical location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            { types: ['geocode'] });
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
        // populate the address fields in the form.
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            fillInAddress();
        });
    }

    // [START region_fillform]
    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;

            }
        }
    }
    // [END region_fillform]

    // [START region_geolocation]
    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }
    // [END region_geolocation]

</script>

<style>
    #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
    }

    #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
    }

    .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
    }

    #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
    }

        #address td {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

    .field {
        width: 99%;
    }

    .slimField {
        width: 80px;
    }

    .wideField {
        width: 200px;
    }

    #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
</style>

<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
        onfocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address" <%--style="visibility: hidden;"--%>>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input class="field" id="street_number"
                disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
            <input class="field" id="route"
                disabled="true"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
            <input class="field" id="locality"
                disabled="true"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input class="field"
                id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField">
            <input class="field" id="postal_code"
                disabled="true"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
            <input class="field"
                id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not get this error when using your code. Could it be that the autocomplete is not yet created when you focus on the autocomplete input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code IS working.

A reference to jQuery is missing, add it with :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just before the inclusion of Google Maps Places library

Comment: Good catch! Here is your working code (without the jQuery document ready) http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/e02tf715/ The autocomplete doesn't exist (as stated in my first comment) because you didn't go through the initialize function because you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: yes, actually Its added at scripts.ascx but somehow doesn't work. let me investigate it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud write like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        initialize(); });
```